# Enable MySQL trigger for all users in mysql

Tags: mysql, trigger

I have setup triggers in my MySQL tables and when I applied them they were restricted to the account I used when creating the triggers, now I have multiple users in my MySQL and I want it so that the triggers will work for all users not just for the one I used when creating them. I currently tried this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`%`@`%` TRIGGER after_atm_account_insert 
    AFTER INSERT ON `system_database`.atm_account
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `log_database`.system_logs
    SET actionDone = 'insert',
        employee = USER(),
        logDate = NOW(),
        tableChange = 'atm_account',
        rowChange = NEW.atmID,
        new_data = concat("Account #",NEW.accountNumber,", Pin:",NEW.pin,", Security Code:",NEW.securityCode,", Withdrawal Limit:",NEW.withdrawalLimit);  

END
```

Answer (score 1):

If you think of the definer as the user that the trigger runs as then it needs the right grants to do whatever the triggers action is.

But it sounds like what you want is for other users to be able to trigger the trigger. In this case all of the users that you need to be able to invoke the trigger need the `trigger` privilege.

See more info here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_trigger

But basically for each user you need to `grant trigger`.

Comment: I think you mean `TRIGGER`, not `GRANT TRIGGER`.

Comment: Updated with suggestion

Comment: I did grant them trigger privileges but it still returns an error saying that the user in the definer should be the one i'm using not the other user. Should i just create the same trigger for the other users?

Comment: The documentation itself states:

`The TRIGGER privilege enables trigger operations. You must have this privilege for a table to create, drop, or execute triggers for that table.`

This is true from MySQL 5.5 to 5.7 so a user with the `trigger` privilege should be able to execute a trigger.

What is the error message you are getting exactly?

Comment: What throws me is "'%'@'%'".  This is not a specific user, so I wonder if it works at all?

Comment: @RickJames actually it doesn't and gives me an error, thus I was wondering if you can give me an alternative to this

Comment: I've only seen specific `user@host` syntax.  I can't find whether wild cards are or are not allowed in the Trigger syntax.